# Dispatch event with data

Tags: javascript, events, custom-events

I'd like to dispatch an event that will pass some data to any event listeners that listen on that event.

Considering a function that fires an event:

```
function click() {
  const x = 'foo'
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('clicked'))
}

click()
```

How can I pass custom data to the event listener?

```
document.addEventListener('clicked', function(e) {
  console.log(x) // logs "foo"
})
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for `event.detail`

```
new CustomEvent('eventName', {'detail': data})
```

Instead of data use x and in event listener you can access x using event.detail

```
function getSelectionBounds() {
  var x = (bounds["x"].toFixed(2));
  var y = "xyz";
  var selectionFired = new CustomEvent("selectionFired", {
    "detail": {"x":x,"y":y }
  });

  document.dispatchEvent(selectionFired);
};

document.addEventListener("selectionFired", function (e) {
  alert(e.detail.x+"   "+e.detail.y);
});
```

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides does this happen in all the browsers can you please update your code using what I suggested or create a fiddle

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides what does alert display in my updated code.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides check my updated answer for multiple variables

Comment: I think you forgot a } in detail but other than that it works like a charm. Many thanks again

Comment: How would you pass data to a custom mouse event? Like new mouseEvent?

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately `CustomEvent` not work on IE (before Edge), but you can simply use the normal `Event`.

Just consider that also `Event` is an object, and so you can add all custom attributes you need:

```
 event.X = "foo";
```

On this way you can check your custom field on the callback function joned to the event.

NB.  For old IE version you need this polyfill for `new Event` missed function:

```
var event;
if(typeof(Event) === 'function') {
  event = new Event(EVENT_NAME);
}else{
  event = document.createEvent('Event');
  event.initEvent(EVENT_NAME, false, false);
}
```