# Pass Data to Event Handler via dispatchEvent or HTMLElement.click

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to pass data to an event handler using either `EventTarget.dispatchEvent()` or `HTMLElement.click()`?

http://jsfiddle.net/yq7yqpL8/1/

```
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('foobar', function() {
    console.log(arguments); // [Event]
});

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(arguments); // [MouseEvent]
});

button.click({ foo: 'bar' });

var event = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
event.initEvent('foobar', true, false);
button.dispatchEvent(event, { foo: 'bar' });
```

Comment: [Take a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23725816/dispatch-event-with-data) maybe it will help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for are custom Events, that can attach custom parameters like so:

```
//Listen for the event
window.addEventListener("foobar", function(evt) {
    alert(evt.detail);
}, false);

//Dispatch an event
var evt = document.createEvent("CustomEvent");
evt.initCustomEvent("foobar", true, true, "Object");
window.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Read along [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9417121/is-there-any-way-of-passing-additional-data-via-custom-events)

Comment: Thanks for responding; confirming this works for the `foobar` event: http://jsfiddle.net/yq7yqpL8/3/. Is there a way to pass data for native UI Events, such as click?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273350/jquery-click-pass-parameters-to-user-function) will help you in that case.
Please mark the answer as solved if it helped you.

Answer (score -3):

This should answer your qestion using jquery:

```
button.bind('click', { name: 'something' }, function(event) {
    alert(event.data.name);
});
```

See also: http://api.jquery.com/event.data/