# How to dispatch a custom event?

Tags: javascript, velo

How I could dispatch a custom event from '#input1' in this function?

What i tried:

```
export function captcha1_verified() {

        $w('#input1').show();
    
        const myEvent = new CustomEvent("myevent", {
            detail: {},
            bubbles: true,
            cancelable: true,
            composed: false,
        });
    
        $w('#input1').dispatchEvent(myEvent);
    }
```

Error: `TypeError: $w(...).dispatchEvent is not a function`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dispatchEvent() is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70080625/dispatchevent-is-not-a-function)

Comment: @Peterrabbit you linked the same question twice, and it didn't answer the question, the problem is finding how to make dispatchEvent work with Wix syntax.

Comment: Yes sorry I got tangled up, and I thought you were with jQuery. Anyway I found this that seems to be the same problem https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/custom-element-dispatch-event

Comment: You can't use dispatchEvent like that on a Wix Element. Maybe try explaining what you're trying to accomplish and we can help you figure out how to do that within Velo.